# 3D Data with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d, contour

I have data in the following form:

```
x <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)
y <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)

xAxis <- x/(1+x*y)
yAxis <- x/(1+x*y)

z <- (0.9-xAxis)^2 + (0.5-yAxis)^2

df <- expand.grid(x,y)
xAxis <- df$Var1/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)
yAxis <- df$Var2/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)

df$x <- xAxis
df$y <- yAxis
df$z <- z
```

I would like to plot te (x,y,z) data as a surface and contour plots, possibily interpolating data to obtain as smooth a figure as possible.

Searching I reached the `akima` package which does the interpolation:

```
im <- with(df,interp(x,y,z))
```

I am having trouble plotting the data with this output. Ideally I would like to use ggplot2 since I want to add stuff to the original plot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled as to what you are looking for, but how about something like this?

```
im <- with(df, akima::interp(x, y, z, nx = 1000, ny = 1000))
df2 <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = im$x, y = im$y), z = c(im$z))

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_raster() + 
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]

Comment: I will check on your solution, but I want to plot a surface and contour plots with those (x,y,z) data. I would imagine that some interpolation would be needed to achieve a more presentable graph.

Answer (score 0):

For contour plots, I use the "rgl" package.  This allows real-time manipulation of the plot in order to have the best view.

```
library("rgl")

x <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)
y <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)

#z <- (0.9-xAxis)^2 + (0.5-yAxis)^2

df <- expand.grid(x,y)
xAxis <- df$Var1/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)
yAxis <- df$Var2/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)

df$z <- (0.9-xAxis)^2 + (0.5-yAxis)^2

surface3d(x=x, y=y, z=df$z, col="blue", back="lines")
title3d(xlab="x", zlab="z", ylab="y")
axes3d(tick="FALSE")
```

The rgl package is comparable to the ggplot2 package to customize the final plot.  The 0.01 grid spacing is more than close enough for this type of smooth surface.

Comment: how can I see the contour?

Comment: I believe the lines3d or planes3d can be used to generate contour lines or even terrain colors could highlight the contours.

Comment: To export the 3D plot to html, use: browseURL(paste("file://", writeWebGL(width=700), sep="")), might be useful